# Upload a text file to a site for analysis using MechanicalSoup

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to get a text file to [TreeTagger Online](http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/treetagger/) to get it analyzed and get the link to the resulting file to download.

```
import mechanicalsoup  
browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
homePage = browser.get("http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/treetagger/")
formPart = homePage.soup.select("form[name=treetagger_form]")[0]
formPart.select("[name=file_to_tag]")[0]["name"]=open('test.txt', 'rb')
result = browser.post(formPart, homePage.url)
```

This gives me the following error:

> : (, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'No connection adapters were found for \'\n\n\n\n\n               Texte \xe0 \xe9tiqueter : \n            \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\'', 216, 217, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))

How should I proceed to get my file on site (using MechanicalSoup or another module)?

---

**01/04/19 Edit**

Even though I did not manage to get @Rolando Urquiza's answer to work on my machine, I was able to get the thing done from his suggestions.

```
import mechanicalsoup  
browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
homePage = browser.get("http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/treetagger/")
formPart = homePage.soup.select("form[name=treetagger_form]")[0]
form=mechanicalsoup.Form(formPart)
form.set('file_to_tag', 'test.txt')
upload=browser.submit(form,url="http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/treetagger/")
```

Thanks @Rolando Urquiza

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of MechanicalSoup, you can upload a file using the `set` function on a `mechanicalsoup.Form` instance, see [here](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mechanicalsoup.html#mechanicalsoup.Form.set). For example, this is how you can use it:

```
import mechanicalsoup  
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.get("http://cental.fltr.ucl.ac.be/treetagger/")
form = browser.select_form()
form.set('file_to_tag', 'test.txt')
result = browser.submit_selected()
```

Comment: This does not work on my installation. The examples given on the demo site do not either... Thanks for your help.

Comment: But the answer led me to a solution that did work on my installation. Thanks so much...